# Node js notification system issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating facebook type notification system using node.js and mysql. i understood concept of node.js but i am confused about how to create complete notification module using node js & mysql. also confused about that how to run from browser. Please help to solve my issue. thanks in advance.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
// Let’s make node/socketio listen on port 3000
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000)
// Define our db creds
var db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    database: 'node'
})

// Log any errors connected to the db
db.connect(function(err){
    if (err) console.log(err)
})

// Define/initialize our global vars
var notes = []
var isInitNotes = false
var socketCount = 0

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // Socket has connected, increase socket count
    socketCount++
    // Let all sockets know how many are connected
    io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        // Decrease the socket count on a disconnect, emit
        socketCount--
        io.sockets.emit('users connected', socketCount)
    })

    socket.on('new note', function(data){
        // New note added, push to all sockets and insert into db
        notes.push(data)
        io.sockets.emit('new note', data)
        // Use node's db injection format to filter incoming data
        db.query('INSERT INTO notes (note) VALUES (?)', data.note)
    })

    // Check to see if initial query/notes are set
    if (! isInitNotes) {
        // Initial app start, run db query
        db.query('SELECT * FROM notes')
            .on('result', function(data){
                // Push results onto the notes array
                notes.push(data)
            })
            .on('end', function(){
                // Only emit notes after query has been completed
                socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
            })

        isInitNotes = true
    } else {
        // Initial notes already exist, send out
        socket.emit('initial notes', notes)
    }
})
```

Comment: i have added code above

Comment: I think you could figure out most of what you want by looking at the socket.io chat demo (https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat).  You're going to need to serve some html pages as well for the browser views and the client side web socket and that is all in the demo.

Comment: @amitnindroda The chat application is really very great and simple to understand example. That is also the starting point for your notification system.